# OAuth 2.0 and php slim

Tags: php, oauth, slim

I am following this guide (http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2013/oauth-middleware-for-slim) to setup oAuth2 with php SLIM.

I dont't understand this part:

```
$auth = new \Service\Mysql\AuthService($this->mysql, $this->config);
            $validated_user_id = $auth->verifyOAuth($authHeader);
            $this->app->user_id = $validated_user_id;
```

Where can I take the class \Service\Mysql\AuthService and what is the variable config ?
Otherwise is there another guide with more details also without direct SLIM implementation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the service class that will actually do the loading and storing of user details.
Then you should put your own class.

This could be useful: https://github.com/alexbilbie/oauth2-example-resource-server